# How src & require with variables work in React?

Tags: reactjs

This work

```
src={require("../uploads/Lumia1520-Front-Back-png.png")}
```

But whis doesn't work

```
src={require(`..${item.image}`)}
```

Error: Cannot find module '../uploads/Lumia1520-Front-Back-png.png'

I don't know what to do with that.
I use create-react-app and accept data from backend rest api.
I would like to implement all this conveniently so that there are no problems with run build.

Comment: This data from backend, all other data from the same product works well and is displayed.
    "image": "/uploads/Lumia1520-Front-Back-png.png",

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem with rendering the path of the image
try

```
src={require(`../uploads/${item.image}`)}
```

Comment: ((((
Error: Cannot find module './/uploads/Lumia1520-Front-Back-png.png'